# Is it possible to access a live video feed from collision-avoidance cameras (DJI’s stereo cameras)?

Tags: dji-sdk

Do we have access to live video feed from the collision avoidance stereo cameras in Dji Drones Mobile SDK?

If it's possible to access, please let me know!

Comment: What is this "DJI"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Company which manufactures Drones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible from the MobileSDK but it's possible from the OnboardSDK which only works on M100, M210 (and RTK), M600 aircrafts and N3/A3 flight controllers.